# mysql query - multilevel locations

Tags: mysql

I've a table with following structure and values:

```
location_id, location_name, parent_id

1,           USA,           0
2,           Illinois,      1
3,           Chicago,       2
4,           New York,      1
```

In this fragment, then row with `'USA'` would be considered a country, because value of `parent_id` is 0. But, if `parent_id` has some other value, then it would signify, that the particular location is under some location. We have multiple levels of location and it is not set. It can be 2 level, 3 level, 4 level, etc.

For ex. *USA > Alabama > Alabama Gulf Coast > Gulf Shores*

I need to get all `location_id` entries, which has no further location. So that in above example, I should get answer as "Gulf Shores".

I think the solution should be something like:

```
SELECT location_id FROM location WHERE "( parent_id does not contain any value from location_id )"
```

But i cannot figure out the exact syntax. How should I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select location_id from location l 
    where not exists 
    (select null 
     from location 
     where parent_id = l.location_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would be better off, if you used [Closure Tables](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html) to implement this ( as recommended in ["SQL Antipatterns"](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book).